# zip() in Shiny web app returning errors even though all files appear to be correct

Tags: r, pdf, zip, shiny, download

I know there are a quite a few questions out there regarding how to download multiple PDF files all at once and they all seem to imply the same thing: my file names got screwed up and it wasn't reading the right file. I tried to correct this with an `if (file.exists(paste0(file, '.zip'))) file.rename(paste0(file, '.zip'), file)` but that didn't work because as `browser()` showed me, the files in my `fileNames` variable were all legit.

I'm not going to post my full ui.R and server.R codes because they're long, but I'll give the abridged version:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  chartInput <- function() {
    if (any(input$target == "Select...",
            input$year == "Select...",
            input$month == "Select...")) return(NULL)
    p <- plotGraph(rawDataDF(), input$target, input$month, input$year)
    print(p)
  }

output$exportMultiple <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "pdfs.zip",
    content = function(file) {
      if (input$target == 'Select...') {
        session$sendCustomMessage(type="showalert", "Need to choose a target first.")
        dev.off()
        return(NULL)
      }
      setwd(tempdir())
      fileNames <- c()
      target <- input$target
      dates <- rawData()$Date[rawData()$Target == target]
      years <- dates %>% as.Date(format="%m/%d/%y") %>% format("%Y") %>% unique()
      for (year in years) {
        months <- dates[paste0("20", substr(dates, 7, 8)) == year] %>%
          as.Date(format="%m/%d/%y") %>% sort %>% format("%B") %>% unique()
          for (month in months) {
            fileName <- paste0(target, ' ', month, ' ', year, '.pdf')
            fileNames <- c(fileNames, fileName)
            pdf(fileName, height=8.5, width=11, paper="a4r")
            chartInput()
            dev.off()
          }
      }
      zip(zipfile="pdfs.zip", files=fileNames)
    },
    contentType = "application/zip"
  )
})
```

The errors I get are:

```
Error opening file: 2
Error reading: 6
```

Using the suggestion of another answer, I run the `browser()` command right after the zip command to look at the files in there and everything is what I would expect. `fileNames` contains the 41 files I would have expected to print and there are other files that I presume are not being included in my zip file since I'm clearly specifying which files it should take. So I'm just confused as to why I'm getting the error and how I might get around it.

Here is my sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.0
```